# Loading shapefiles from a read-only drive

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3

Never had a problem with that, but after updating to ArcGIS 10.3 I cannot load shapefiles from a read-only drive. The error message says:

Error opening feature class
FDO error: -1 [nnn.shp]
FDO error: -1 [nnn.shp]

After clicking OK the following warning occurs:

Could not add the specified data object to the map.
FDO erro: -1 [nnn.shp]

Still I am able to open the shapefiles using other GIS tools. Probably ArcGIS 10.3 is trying to write a lock file into the folder. Everything worked fine in ArcGIS 10.0.

Comment: Which tool, and what parameters, are you using to try and load shapefiles?